# Linear Algebra - Determinant of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

So I'm working through sample questions and this came up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Question***

Let $V$ be the vector space of all complex-valued polynomials $p(x)$ of degree at most $42$ and consider the linear transformation $L\colon V\to V$ given by:

$L(p(x)) = -p^{\prime\prime}(x) + 22p(x)$, where $p^{\prime\prime}$ is the second derivative of $p$.

(a)State the definition of $\det(L)$

(b)Find $\det(L)$. Justify your answer!

***Progress***

(a) I used Leibniz' definition where $$\det(L) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}sgn(\sigma)\prod^n_{i=1}a_{i,\sigma(i)}$$
 for some $a\in L$.

(b) I know how to get the determinant for a matrix but I don't understand it here. Thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

Comment: In order to use that definition of determinant (the most formal one there is),  you *already have* to know the matrix representation of $\;L\;$ wrt some basis of $\;V\;$ . Do you? If you don't then you must try to get one, say wrt the usual basis $\;\{1,x,x^2,...,x^{42}\}\;$

Comment: What if I use det(A) = Σ$a_nC_n$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\begin{align}&L(1)=22\\
&L(x)=22x\\
&L(x^2)=2+22x^2\\
&\ldots\;\ldots\;\ldots\\
&L(x^k)=k(k-1)x^{k-2}+22x^k\\
&\ldots\;\ldots\;\ldots\\
&L(x^{42})=42\cdot41x^{40}+22x^42\end{align}\;\;\;\implies\;\;[L]^t=\begin{pmatrix}22&0&0&\ldots&0\\
0&22&0&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&\ldots&42\cdot41&0&22\end{pmatrix}$$

Since $\;\det A=\det A^t\;$ for any matrix, the above is enough to know what you need.

Comment: Could I use det(L) = $a^n + (-1)^{n+1}.b^n$? If I can is a = 22? And what is b?

Comment: @teme92 I've no idea what you mean by $\;a_n\,,\,\,b_n\;$ ...